# What software tools or websites are available for running RPG, grid-based combat?

Tags: combat, tools, map-making, online-resources

Are there any software tools (or websites) that support creating tactical combat maps as well as actively running them for combat? I'm looking to do away with paper and battle-mats. Here are my requirements:

- Can create floor plans with tiles.
- Can put (or draw) objects to that tiles. It doesn't necessarily have to be real object models (3d). It would be sufficient enough if you can draw lines/squares/circles etc.
- Can add (put, draw) PCs and NPCs to that tiles and move them.

I'm going  use it for my GURPS games. I want to keep track of my players and NPCs movements with software. I don't want to bother using real paper. It could be more practical to use software for that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**[Roll20.net](http://roll20.net/) is going to be your best friend**

First off its free. COMPLETELY FREE.

Roll20 has a built in grid with the ability to use their library and import images to lay as background under their grids. Player tokens can work in much the same way. The system has integrated chat dice rolling and even programmable buttons players and the GM can create to auto roll a bunch of stuff together (for example to-hit and damage rolls for an attack, at the same time).  It also has built in video and audio chat. You can draw over maps, create fog of war, and all sorts of other wonderful, GM friendly abilities.

I've used Roll20.net for multiple campaigns playing D&D 4e and had lots of success with it. GM/whomever is hosting the campaign can go in ahead of time and create all sorts of maps and (pages in Roll20). Players always start on page 1 and the GM advances them to the next map only when they want to.

There are also lots of other nice systems that basically allow you to track health and other resources as well as store character sheets and other RPG info in the system and administer who has read only and read & write access.

Comment: Roll20 also has some advanced features only available to paid accounts; most notably, dynamic lightning and access to the scripting API. Only the campaign creator needs to have the paid account in order to enable the features in the campaign.